# Bash: echo extract variables

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose there's a script called 'test.sh':

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    APP=/apps echo "$line"
done < ./lines
```

And the 'lines':

```
cd $APP && pwd
```

If I `bash test.sh`, it prints out 'cd $APP && pwd'.

But when I type `APP=/apps echo "cd $APP && pwd"` in the terminal, it prints out 'cd /apps && pwd'.

Is it possible using `echo` to extract variables which are reading from a regular file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the contents of the file, you may want to use eval:

```
#!/bin/bash
APP=/apps
while read line; do
    eval "echo \"$line\""  # WARNING: dangerous
done < ./lines
```

However, eval is extremely dangerous.  Although the quoting here will work for simple cases, it is quite easy to execute arbitrary commands by manipulating the input.

Comment: Apologies, I had quoted things incorrectly.  Fixed now.  Note that this is still extremely fragile.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `eval` to evaluate string line read from file

Comment: But `eval` will evaluate `pwd` too..Maybe I just need some function like template.

Comment: `eval echo <string>` should work without evaluating commands within `string`. Willian Pursell's answer includes the complete code for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the variable(s) you want to substitute, just substitute them.

```
sed 's%\$APP\>%/apps%g' ./lines
```